# Passing Django variable in template JS

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am using the Django framework. In my template I have an variable `{{i.slot.place.latitude}}` and other is `{{i.slot.place.longitude}}`
I want to use these variables in java script with google map. which is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng({{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}} ,{{ interview.slot.location.place.longitude }});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter
    });`
```

here in `google.maps.LatLng` I am trying to give these variable but it's not working. Can somebody tell me the right way?

Comment: Use this `var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('{{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}}', '{{ interview.slot.location.place.longitude }}')`

Comment: I have tried this but not working

Comment: Is `{{i.slot.place.latitude}}` the same as `{{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}}`?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically generate JS? So please show your view. Also note that you say you use `{{i.slot.place.latitude}}` but in your template you refer to `{{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}}`...

Comment: Then put them in js vars: `var lat = '{{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}}'` and `var lng = '{{ interview.slot.location.place.longitude }}'` and then pass as params `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: @Jingo Yaa it's {{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}} and everywhere i am using this only

Comment: @Gocht I have tried this also but did not get any result

Comment: What does `{{interview.slot.location.place.latitude}}` print if you render it in the template?

Comment: when i print it somewhere in template it gives me 19.4345544 but inside JS it gives null - ' '

Comment: Is it numeric or string? If numeric, try sending it as string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize data in your view manually https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/